# Regular expression to isolate lines without comma

Tags: regex, visual-studio

How to isolate lines that do not contain 4 commas using regular expressions on a microsoft IDE- like VS or MSSQL

Example below

```
abcd,efg,hi,jk,a
abd,fef,rgr,ht
abd,aad,rhrhr,rtre
dfsf,sdf,sfsdf,sd,fs
```

in the above example, i need to isolate lines

```
abd,fef,rgr,ht
abd,aad,rhrhr,rtre
```

since they do not have 4 commas

Comment: The second line also has only three commas. Also, can a line start or end with a comma?

Comment: yes.. the line may start with comma. just worried about count of commas

Comment: Do you want lines with more than 4 comma's as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Visual Studio (2012):**

```
^(?![^,\n]*,[^,\n]*,[^,\n]*,[^,\n]*,).*$
```

or, simplified:

```
^(?!([^,\n]*,){4}).*$
```

**In SQL Server Management Studio (2012):**

```
^~([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,).*$
```

**Explanation:**

Both of the above assume we must exclude lines that contain 4 or more commas. To make it such that you only exclude lines containing exactly 4 commas, simply add `[^,\n]*$` and `[^,]*$` respectively to the part in brackets, i.e.:

```
^(?![^,\n]*,[^,\n]*,[^,\n]*,[^,\n]*,[^,\n]$).*$
^(?!([^,\n]*,){4}[^,\n]$).*$
^~([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]$).*$
```

Both make use of negative look-ahead (see [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more details), they just require different syntax.

Additionally, in SSMS you don't need the new-line (`\n`) check (but including it doesn't change much) and the `{4}` syntax doesn't seem to work.

`^` - start of line.

`(?!...)` or `~(...)` - syntax for negative look-ahead.

`[^,\n]*` - zero or more characters that aren't commas or new-lines.

`[^,]*` - zero or more characters that aren't commas.

`.*` - zero or more of anything.

`$` - end of line.

`{4}` - exactly 4 occurrences of whatever appears before it.

**Why not just this?**

```
^(?!.*,.*,.*,.*,).*$
```

Someone may have argued that you can just use the above, but this would actually be slower, as it would require backtracking as the first `.*` will try to match the entire line, then it will backtrack to the last `,` and the next `.*` will match the entire line, and then it will backtrack to the second last `,`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to work for me:

```
(^(\w*?,){0,3}\w*$|^(\w*?,){5,}\w*$)
```

It searches for lines containing 0 to 3 or 5 and more occurrences of commas. Feel free to substitute `\w` with whatever character class is necessary.

Example: http://www.regex101.com/r/aZ0wI3

Comment: +1, interesting approach. Though `[^,\n]` instead of `\w` would be more general.

Comment: @Dukeling Ergo the note about substituting it for w/e replacement you see fit :-) Even though `[^,\n]` is the least restrictive, if he doesn't need it to be, it should be limited to the smallest subset of possible occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .+,.+,.+,.+,.+
It will match all texts with 4 commas (assuming line doesn't start with comma, doesn't end with comma, theres atleast one character between 2 commas)

Comment: for exactly 4 commas, wherever they are  [^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*

Comment: This gives lines containing 4 (or more) commas, not all the other lines (which is what OP wants).

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that. Thought he could just take the set that doesn't match, like a !=